# Mqtt subscribe message while continuous publishing to topic

Tags: python, mqtt

I am trying to Publish message to topic "New/Topic" and subscribe message from another topic "OK/Topic"
but it doesn't work following is my code :

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("OK/Topic")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(" Topic : "+str(msg.topic)+"  and Message is : "+str(msg.payload))

def on_subscribe(client, userdata,mid, granted_qos):
    print "userdata : " +str(userdata)


strs="my-message-to-publish"
mqttc = mqtt.Client("Python-MQTT-Pub-Sub")
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.connect("IP", PORT, 60)

while True:
    mqttc.publish("New/Topic",str(strs))
    print "publish message " + str(strs)
    time.sleep(1)

mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Anyone knows how to subscribe message while continuous publishing to topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will never terminate so the code will never reach the mqttc.loop_start() function. This is what's causing the problem you are seeing.

If you move the mqttc.loop_start call to before the while loop it should do better as it will start the background thread to handle the incoming messages (and to actually send the published messages)

Comment: Thanks hardlib..  i miss mqttc.loop_forever() , now i have updated main post.

Comment: You don't want loop_forever, you want loop_start

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work perfectly:

```
while True:
        client.connect(broker_address, port)
        message = 'msg'      
        client.publish(topic, message)
        time.sleep(1)
client.loop_forever()`
```

Comment: This won't work, again you will never reach the `client.loop_forever()` and it you should not be reconnecting on each time round the loop. Finally it will not work for any message bigger than the network MTU.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to publish data while subscribing

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Received message: " + str(msg.payload))

# Create MQTT client
client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_message = on_message

# Connect to MQTT broker
client.connect("192.168.8.10", 1883)

# Start the MQTT loop
client.loop_start()

client.subscribe("topic1")
client.subscribe("topic2")

try:
    while True:
        # Publish data every 5 minutes
        data = random.randint(1, 100)
        client.publish("topic3", str(data))
        print("Published data:", data)
        time.sleep(10)  # 5 minutes

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Stop the MQTT loop
    client.loop_stop()
    print("MQTT loop stopped")

# Disconnect from MQTT broker
client.disconnect()
```